# Server return http status 415 when I send json string

Tags: java, jersey

My server have an api. This api need to using POST and bring the json string in the request body.

I create a class and property to match the json. Then my api using this class for a parameter.

In my case has an special point, I have a sub class in the main class and sub class write in the main class.

My testing result is, if I write the sub class in the main class then the server will return 415 error. (Two class are in the same .class file)

If I separate these two class, main class in one class file and sub class in another class file. Then import sub class in main class. It's work.

HTTP status 415. All class in a class file.

```
public class CreateWorkstageByCusDataModel {

    String document_id;
    AdditionInfoModel addition_info;

    public CreateWorkstageByCusDataModel() {

    }

    public class AdditionInfoModel {

        public AdditionInfoModel() {

        }

        String record_number;

        public String getRecord_number() {
            return record_number;
        }

        public void setRecord_number(String record_number) {
            this.record_number = record_number;
        }
   }
    public String getDocument_id() {
        return document_id;
    }

    public void setDocument_id(String document_id) {
        this.document_id = document_id;
    }

    public AdditionInfoModel getAddition_info() {
        return addition_info;
    }

    public void setAddition_info(AdditionInfoModel addition_info) {
        this.addition_info = addition_info;
    }
}
```

Working code. Separate two class to two class file

```
public class CreateWorkstageByCusDataModel {

    String document_id;
    CreateWorkstageByCusDataAdditionModel addition_info;

    public String getDocument_id() {
        return document_id;
    }

    public void setDocument_id(String document_id) {
        this.document_id = document_id;
    }

    public CreateWorkstageByCusDataAdditionModel getAddition_info() {
        return addition_info;
    }

    public void setAddition_info(CreateWorkstageByCusDataAdditionModel addition_info) {
        this.addition_info = addition_info;
    }

}
```

```
public class CreateWorkstageByCusDataAdditionModel {

    String record_number;

    public String getRecord_number() {
        return record_number;
    }

    public void setRecord_number(String record_number) {
        this.record_number = record_number;
    }

}
```

Can anyone explain this problem, I am curious what the different between these two case. Or how can I modify my code to make way 1 correct.(Main class and sub class in same file)

Comment: Your first two (larger) code blocks look the same. Where's the difference? I assume it has to do with `CreateWorkstageByCusDataAdditionModel` but you posted only the class itself not how it is used. If your problem is with the inner class `AdditionInfoModel` (from your description it looks like it is) then try to make the inner class static. In your current case the inner class is tied to the outer instance and I assume the Json library in use can't deal with that (at least not with additional measures). To help more we'd need more info though, e.g. some stacktraces etc.

Comment: @Thomas, Sorry it's some mistake when I post this question. I had correct the question. I will try to add static in my sub class and see the result.

Comment: @Thomas Yes,your are right. After I change the sub class to static class, I can get into my api successfully and did't get any error. Thanks